# Azure Text Sentiment

Tags: python, azure, sentiment-analysis, azure-cognitive-services

Im trying to azure sentiment analysis api

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient

credential = AzureKeyCredential("<api_key>")
endpoint="https://<region>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/"

text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint, credential)

documents = [
    "I did not like the restaurant. The food was too spicy.",
    "The restaurant was decorated beautifully. The atmosphere was unlike any other restaurant I've been to.",
    "The food was yummy. :)"
]

response = text_analytics_client.analyze_sentiment(documents, language="en")
result = [doc for doc in response if not doc.is_error]

for doc in result:
    print("Overall sentiment: {}".format(doc.sentiment))
    print("Scores: positive={}; neutral={}; negative={} \n".format(
        doc.confidence_scores.positive,
        doc.confidence_scores.neutral,
        doc.confidence_scores.negative,
    ))
```

This code works fine, but I want to read a df column, get the text sentiment and create a column to storage the text sentiment, do you know how can i do it? I have tried to pass `documents = df['column_name']` and `df[I]`, but I get error

Answer (score 1):

The following code should give you a dataframe with two columns, one to hold the document text and the other to hold the corresponding sentiment:

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

documents = [
    "I did not like the restaurant. The food was too spicy.",
    "The restaurant was decorated beautifully. The atmosphere was unlike any other restaurant I've been to.",
    "The food was yummy. :)"
]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Documents"] = documents

response = text_analytics_client.analyze_sentiment(documents, language="en")
result = [doc for doc in response if not doc.is_error]

for doc in result:
    df["Sentiment"] = doc.sentiment
    print("Overall sentiment: {}".format(doc.sentiment))
    print("Scores: positive={}; neutral={}; negative={} \n".format(
        doc.confidence_scores.positive,
        doc.confidence_scores.neutral,
        doc.confidence_scores.negative,
    ))

print(tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df.columns))
```

Output:

```
Documents                                                                                               Sentiment
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -----------
I did not like the restaurant. The food was too spicy.                                                  positive
The restaurant was decorated beautifully. The atmosphere was unlike any other restaurant I've been to.  positive
The food was yummy. :)                                                                                  positive
```